# How to replace my Grid with the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With this i can make a gird like 3x3 but if i want to make a new one it will stack on the old grid so how do i remove the old grid so i can see the new one?

Example of this:
I type 3 into row and column and click the button it will then make a grid 3x3.
Then i will try again and make the grid 5x5 so i type 5 into row and column but it just stack it on the old grid so how do i replace it with the new grid?

```js
$(document).on("click","#gridBtn",function()
{
    
  

// Cal the size of the Main div 
var mapHeight = $("#theMap").height();  // 400 
var mapWidth = $("#theMap").width();  // 400 

// divide it BY 
var rowsLeft = $("#rowValue").val(); 
var columnsTop = $("#columnValue").val(); 

// Cal the size of the box 
var divideHeight = mapHeight / columnsTop;   // 100 
var divideWidth = mapWidth / rowsLeft;     // 100


for (var i = 0; i < rowsLeft; i++) {
 
         $("#theMap").append('<div class="row" style="height:'+divideHeight+'px; width: auto;"></div>');
    }


for (var i = 0; i < columnsTop; i++) {
 
         $(".row").append('<div class="square" style="height:'+divideHeight+'px; width:'+divideWidth+'px;"></div>');
    }



});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#theMap {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.square {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gold inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    
  <div id="theMap"></div>
  
  <div id="inputWrapper">
    <input id="rowValue" type="text" placeholder="rows">
     <input id="columnValue" type="text" placeholder="columns">
     <button id="gridBtn">Create grid</button>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply added `$("#theMap").html("");` to the start of the function, to clearthe contents of `#theMap`. Is this what you are wanting?

```js
$(document).on("click","#gridBtn",function()
{
    
$("#theMap").html("");

// Cal the size of the Main div 
var mapHeight = $("#theMap").height();  // 400 
var mapWidth = $("#theMap").width();  // 400 

// divide it BY 
var rowsLeft = $("#rowValue").val(); 
var columnsTop = $("#columnValue").val(); 

// Cal the size of the box 
var divideHeight = mapHeight / columnsTop;   // 100 
var divideWidth = mapWidth / rowsLeft;     // 100


for (var i = 0; i < rowsLeft; i++) {
 
         $("#theMap").append('<div class="row" style="height:'+divideHeight+'px; width: auto;"></div>');
    }


for (var i = 0; i < columnsTop; i++) {
 
         $(".row").append('<div class="square" style="height:'+divideHeight+'px; width:'+divideWidth+'px;"></div>');
    }



});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#theMap {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.square {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gold inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    
  <div id="theMap"></div>
  
  <div id="inputWrapper">
    <input id="rowValue" type="text" placeholder="rows">
     <input id="columnValue" type="text" placeholder="columns">
     <button id="gridBtn">Create grid</button>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean the previous "created table" before create a new one, I would try something like:

```
   $("#theMap").val(''); // cleans before append again

   $(".row").val('');  // cleans before append again
```